# Alloy analyzer not finding examples that were found before applying predicate with cardinality constraint

Tags: alloy

I was playing around with alloy trying to build a model to represents steps a user might take while filling a wizard form. I was trying to model his steps using a graph that is connected and always has a path to the final step.

After coming up with the initial model I wanted to see examples of the structure that had more than 3 arcs connecting the nodes.

It turns out that if I use an empty predicate, execute and look at the instances it finds, I can find one that has more than 3 arcs. But when I ask for that explicitly in the predicate, alloy tells me: `No instance found`:

```
pred example (f: Flow) {
  #f.paths > 3
}
```

Am I using the cardinality operator wrong?

Entire model below:

```
sig FlowObject {}

sig Flow {
  steps: set FlowObject,
  initial_step: steps,
  final_step: steps,
  paths: (steps - final_step)->(steps - initial_step),
} {
  // The final step is reachable from every step
  all s: (steps - final_step) | final_step in s.^paths
  // Every step is reachable from the initial step
  all s: (steps - initial_step) | s in initial_step.^paths
  // There are no loops
  no iden & paths
}

// No FlowObject is shared between Flows
fact {
  all f1, f2: Flow | f1 != f2 => no f1.steps & f2.steps
}

pred example (f: Flow) {
  // It finds this example if I remove this predicate
  #f.paths > 3
}

run example for 5 but 1 Flow
```

Comment: In Alloy 5, there's an instance. If you are using Alloy 4, try something like `run example for 5 but 1 Flow, 5 Int` and see if it works.

Comment: That worked! But why?

Comment: Cardinality operator requires ints. In Alloy 4, by default ints are not included (presumably for efficiency), so you need tell Alloy that you need ints explicitly.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much! If you want you can post this answer and I will accept it.